# Can I remove jquery datepicker yearRange

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, datepicker

I am working with a library that provides default yearRange.
I would like to use minDate and maxDate but they seem to be interfering with each other.

According to http://keith-wood.name/datepickref.html
for shortYearCutoff  Since 3.5.2 - disable with -1.

Can this be done with -1 or some other mechanism for year range. (I am stuck with this because of other functionality that the module provides and the yearRange is provided by default.

(I added min/maxDate with firebug after creation so I just need to wipe out the yearRange)

G

Answer (score 0):

Your question is not clear of what outcome you are expecting.

If you want year to be fixed, try this,
declare variables as follows:

```
var currentYear = (new Date()).getFullYear();
```

and then in the datepicker function, you can say,

```
yearRange: currentYear + ":" + currentYear
```